# Can the parameter epsfcn be specified in lmfit to approximate the Jacobian?

Tags: lmfit

I want to specify the `epsfcn` value for the `leastsq` option in `lmfit`. Can the `epsfcn` value be specified?

Comment: I actually have the same question, but I wonder if this keyword can be passed while using the `Model()` class. My guess would be that keyword arguments should be passed to `minimize()` through `model.fit()`. That does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Here it is: `model.fit(...... , fit_kws = {'epsfcn':1e-7})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. The keyword argument `espfcn` can be added to the `minimize` function and is automatically passed on to the `leastsq` function. I hadn't seen that in the documentation of the `minimize` function. It works great.